# Android 11. ContentResolver.query return empty cursor

Tags: android, manifest, android-contentresolver, android-11

I have implemented the selection of contacts from the phone book in my application.
In order for the intent with action PICK to work on android 11, I added this to my manifest:

```
  <queries>
  <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone_v2" />
        </intent>
</queries>
```

The code works fine on android versions 10 and below.
But on android version 11, the contact I selected from the phone book is not inserted into the text field of my application, because ContentResolver.query return empty cursor. it.moveToFirst() returns false
Here is my code:

```
  Constants.START_PICK_CONTACT_ACTION -> {
                data?.data?.let { uri ->
                    activity.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use {
                                if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                                    val number: String? = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                                        etPhoneNumber.setText(number)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
            }
```

Please, help me.

Comment: You do not need `<queries>` for that code, though you might from some other code. By "empty cursor", do you mean it is a valid `Cursor` but has no rows (so `it.moveToFirst()` returns `false`)?

Comment: @CommonsWare, Without <queries> queryIntentActivities return null. Yes, it.moveToFirst() returns false

Comment: "Without <queries> queryIntentActivities return null" -- agreed, but that code is not in your question. In your `query()` call, try specifying the projection that you need (2nd parameter) instead of passing `null`, and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare,The cursor is still empty(

Comment: @testovtest Were you able to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you added `android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS` permission in manifest?

Answer (score 6):

I've had a similar issue. Need to grant `android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS` permission before trying to call query

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. After trying many times, I found that:

**a)** Please double check if you have declared `READ_CONTACTS` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`. If yes, we need to gain the runtime permission for `READ_CONTACTS`. Otherwise the ContentResolver.query() just return an empty cursor.

AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<manifest>
...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
...
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
      <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone_v2" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
</manifest>
```

Code snippet:

```
activity?.let {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(it, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //openContact()
    } else {
        requestPermissions(
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
            REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_CONTACT_CODE
        )
    }
}

...

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
  // openContact()
}
```

**b)** If there is no declaration of `READ_CONTACTS` permission in manifest, just add query element is enough.

AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<manifest>
...
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
...
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
      <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone_v2" />
    </intent>
  </queries>
</manifest>
```

But I cannot find any documentation can explain this behavior, does anyone know the root cause? Would appreciate it very much if you could tell.